# Regular expression prices

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a valid price validation for my needs..

**Valid** input format (xxx means no maximum length - 0000 means 4 decimal places at maximum):

```
15,0000
15.0000
150.0000
150,0000
xxxxxxxxxxxx.0000
xxxxxxxxxxxx,0000
15,00
15,1
15.00
15.1
```

**Invalid** input format (basically everything that starts by 0):

```
01.0000
01.00
01
```

My regular expression so far: `^\$?[1-9][1-9,]*[0-9]\.?[0-9]{0,2}$`

**Edit 1**: Changed my regex for this one: `^\$?[1-9]*[1-9]((\,)|(\.))?[0-9]{0,4}$` but now I need to be able  to add `150000000` and it only allows me `150000`

Comment: What language are you using? Number validation where you permit commas and a single decimal is a little more complicated than you want to tackle with a single regular expression.  Often there are libraries that will offer more robust solutions.  Your existing regexp, for example, allows multiple commas, like `$9,,,,,,,,,0.0`.  Also, `100` is permitted, or even `1,0.`.  Is that ok?

Comment: See my edited post. Language programing? I'll use Javascript and PHP. Yes, 100 is permitted and 1,0 also.

Comment: My suggestion is to strip what is irrelevant (such as commas and currency signs), and then pass it through JavaScript's `IsNumeric`.  After determining that it's numeric, then verify it's within a legal range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this one seems okay to me

```
^[^0]\d+(\.|\,)?[0-9]{0,4}$
```

checked here http://rubular.com/r/97Ra9VS9h4

and yes one more thing if you want to check for one digit numbers also like 1,2 etc

then you can just replace the `+` with `*` like this `^[^0]\d*(\.|\,)?[0-9]{0,4}$`

Comment: But it allows number without comma or point. From his valid numbers every number has at least one comma or one point.

Comment: he has said 4 decimal places maximum, SO minimum can be zero also right ?

Comment: yes, if minimum is zero its right. Just wanted to point that out.

Comment: @aelor, wait a second. It was my fault not to put the valid example on my topic..but this does not work for `1` or `1.21` or `1,21`. How can I solve it?

Comment: I have already updated my answer for that, just replace + with * and it will work for single digits also

Comment: Solved. `/^[0-9]+(\.|\,)?[0-9]{0,4}$/`

Comment: The one you have mentioned here will not omit numbers starting with 0

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: just saw that you updated the question and added 0 as a valid input. I'll see if I can add that.

How about:

```
^([1-9].*[,\.][0-9]*)$
```

This will work on the examples above.

But be careful with input like 15x,001

[See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/wP1xV2)

Comment: The only problem with your regex was the string in the middle and I only want numbers.

Although your regex is more perceptible I've accepted @aelor answer because it's full correct.

Comment: @aelor's answer is not correct until it is updated to use * instead of + for the \d check at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
^\$?[1-9][0-9]*(,|\.)[0-9]{1,4}$
```

The first regex makes sure the price doesnt starts with a zero.
Then all numbers are allowed, zero or more numbers.
Then there must be a comma or a point.
Finaly all numbers are allowed, max count is four and minimum one

Answer (score 0):

```
^[1-9][0-9]*([.,][0-9]{1,4})?$
```